# JS/CoffeScript Call a method when an object is constructed

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following code

```
class MyCompo
  constructor: (component) ->
    @component = $(component)
    @setEvents()

  setEvents: ->
    @component.on "click", @handleMyEvent

  handleMyEvent: =>
    ...
```

that works just fine.

Now I need to fire `handleMyEvent` also when the object is constructed.
I have tried with `DOMNodeInserted` as follows

```
 setEvents: ->
    @component.on "DOMNodeInserted", @handleMyEvent
    @component.on "click", @handleMyEvent
```

but I have some strange behavior (the method is called multiple times and not for all objects).

After further research, I found out that `DOMNodeInserted` even deprecated.

Is there an event that is fired when the object is constructed?

I know I could add it to the constructor itself but if possible I'd rather keeping everything on setEvents`.

Thanks

Comment: You want a `=>` fat arrow in the `setEvents: ->`

Comment: Rule of the thumb: use `=>` if `@` is in the body method (some exceptions apply)